# "Герои с нашего двора" — правильно ли выбран предлог?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

По городу идёт реклама: *"Герои **с** нашего двора"*.

Хотелось бы узнать, почему выбран предлог **"с"**, а не **"из"**?

Answer (score 3):

Обе предложные формы употребляются почти  одинаково часто: из нашего двор (33) и с нашего двора (45) (данные из Нацкорпуса). Возможно, здесь сказывается влияние фильма "Ребята с нашего двора" (1959 год).

Мы говорим: ребята из нашего дома (из здания)  и ребята с нашей улицы (с территории). А вот двор можно понять и как замкнутое пространство, и как территорию, поэтому используются оба предлога.

Примеры

Ребята с нашего двора и улицы быстро забыли, кому принадлежал когда-то велосипед с малиновым фонариком. [Фазиль Искандер.  1987]

Она остается своей, дворовой, из нашего двора, верной подругой. [Андрей Вознесенский. На виртуальном ветру (1998)]